# Getting error in seed.rb when I do rake db:seed was aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I'm trying to create some data in the seed.rb file. When I try to do the `rake db:seed` I have this error:

```
    $ rake db:seed
/Users/romenigld/workspace/ebook/beginning_rails_4_3rd_edition/blog/db/seeds.rb:1: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/romenigld/workspace/ebook/beginning_rails_4_3rd_edition/blog/db/seeds.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input
Category.create([{:name => 'Programmi...
...                               ^
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:183:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My seed.rb file:

```
user = User.create :email => 'mary@example.com', :password => 'guessit'

Category.create([{:name => 'Programming'},
                 {:name => 'Event'},
                 {:name => 'Travel'},
                 {:name => 'Music'},
                 {:name => 'TV'}])
```

My user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :articles, -> { order('published_at DESC, title ASC')},
                      :dependent => :nullify
end
```

My category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

My article.rb:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title, :body

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  def long_title
    "#{title} - #{published_at}"
  end
end
```

Before I create an articles_categories:

```
class CreateArticlesCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles_categories, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :article
      t.references :category
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :articles_categories
  end
end
```

and create the model Category:

```
class CreateArticlesCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles_categories, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :article
      t.references :category
    end
  end
  def self.down
    drop_table :articles_categories
  end
end
```

Comment: Is that your whole `seeds.rb` file, or just a snippet?

Comment: hello michael I'm following a ebook and for now this is the whole content. thank's!

Comment: Try Marko's answer below if you copied and pasted this code. Judging by the warning above the error, the line contains a \r character, which could be causing your error. It's a carriage return character, so you see nothing but a normal line break.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving is simply a syntax error.
This is some code from the example Rails provides in their seed.rb

```
# Examples:
#
#   cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
#   Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)
```

Here is your code.

```
Category.create([{:name => 'Programming'},
             {:name => 'Event'},
             {:name => 'Travel'},
             {:name => 'Music'},
             {:name => 'TV'}])
```

Try reformatting your code to the syntax the example provides -

```
Category.create([
             { name: 'Programming'},
             { name: 'Event'},
             { name: 'Travel'},
             { name: 'Music'},
             { name: 'TV'}
           ])
```

I believe with seeding the db the only time you use hash rockets is outside of an array in reference to seeding, I could be wrong though, just a thought.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The two styles are interchangeable. The hash rocket is the old way; the 'key: value' way is newer. Both are legitimate.

Comment: Oh, okay. I wasn't sure, because I've ran into some weird problems like this in the past. Just wanted to make sure that wasn't it.

Please update if you find a solution I'm curious as to what it is

Comment: So I just did some research on the whole hash rocket syntax and seeding.

It's gotta be something with the syntax on the first line.

That error, from what I saw generally had to do with forgetting to end something right before where the error is being thrown. I would check the syntax for the hash rocket way of doing it to make sure it's correct. Good luck!